# How can I find the general solution to the boundary value problem in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, boundary-value-problem

[image]

I learned how to find the boundary value problem for upper half region by considering $F(x,y) = arg(z-z_0)+B$ and for vertical wall, $F(x,y) = Ax + B$.

However, in this case, it seems like that it is combination of above two cases.

So, in general how can I find the solution?

Comment: Choose branch cut of the argument function $\arg$ as $[0, \infty)$ so that it takes values in $[0, 2\pi)$. Then $\arg = 0$ along the positive real line and $\arg = 3\pi/2$ along the negative imaginary axis. Now translate it and apply a suitable linear function on it.

Comment: Shall I choose function f(x.y)=Aarg(z-1)+B for [0,2pi)?

Comment: Very close but you may want to translate by $1+i$, not just by $1$. Also it is good for others to format your formulas using $\LaTeX$. It would greatly improve the readability.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, but If I choose arg for [0,2pi), then this is not analytic along the positive axis and if we translate by 1+i, then the function would not be analytic ant x+iy for x>1?

Comment: shouldn't it be a branch cut for (0,2pi]?

Comment: Just to make sure, you said we should translate it by 1+i, then the function is f(x.y)=Aarg(x+iy-1-i)+B for branch cut (0,2pi], then how can I find constant A and B for this boundary?

Comment: The (translated) branch cut is part of the boundary of the prescribed region, and we do not need analyticity along the boundary. But some regularity conditions like 'sort of continuity toward boundary' (whose precise meaning I would not introduce here) should be satisfied. That said, if you choose the branch cut $(0, 2\pi]$ then $\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0} \arg(x +i\epsilon) = 0 \neq 2\pi = \arg(x)$ ($x>0$) and we lose continuity toward boundary.

Comment: And $a, b$ can be determined by computing your function on the boundary. I hope you can do the rest as I have to go to bed...